# How to store Dynamics CRM solution in DevOps Repo

Tags: azure-pipelines, dynamics-crm, azure-repos

I am using Wael Hamze's great library to export CRM solutions. I would like to archive the zip files, preferably in a Repository folder.
I have selected the Repos folder as the output path. While the export was successful there are no ZIP files added.
What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: I am not sure from the response that I received if my question was understood. i want to store the raw solution (.zip) file in the repos so that i can import the same solution to other development/test environments. I do not need to unpack them as part of the pipeline. i just want to archive them as is.

Comment: Please refer to this official documentation : [Approach for Merging Dynamics CRM Solutions with DevOps implementations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/approach-for-merging-dynamics-crm-solutions-with-devops-implementations/) to see if helpful to you.

Comment: my problem is not merging or unpacking the solutions. my goal is to archive the solution - as is- somewhere

Comment: try to use the SolutionPackager tool as I modified the answer says.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you look at PowerPlatform Build Tools (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tools) and PowerApps CLI (PAC) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/powerapps-cli

Build tools integrates directly into DevOps pipelines and will Unzip and Zip solutions for you natively.

You can run PAC commands through powershell and do everything that Build tools won't do.

You can commit from a yml pipeline using a script task similar to the following:

```
- script: |
    echo commit all changes
    git config user.email "chris.fernando@mydomain.com"
    git config user.name "Automatic Build"
    git checkout main
    git add --all
    git commit -m "$(pa.environmentPrefrix) portal commit for build $(Build.BuildNumber)"
    
    echo push code to new $(Build.SourceBranch)
    git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push origin $(Build.SourceBranch)
  displayName: 'Commit $(Build.BuildNumber) changes'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am using Power Platform Tools. I am able to export the solution. i can publish the solution to the artifacts folder. I can create a Release pipeline to then import the solution to another environment. What I would like to do is to archive a copy of the ZIP/solution in case i need to use it again. Unpacking is not a solution because i do not plan to download the file to a local PC. I just want to archive it in the project Repos location....

Comment: Wouldn't you just commit the zip from the pipeline?  We commit both the zip and the unpacked components, though really we can just repack the xmls if needed.

Comment: what task do you use to commit from the pipeline?

Comment: I've used Script tasks in my yml pipelines. These comments are bad at displaying yml, so I edited my answer with a sample.

Comment: hmmm. i've been using the Classic Pipelines... i'll see if i can do it in PS as you suggested...thx

Comment: Welcome to come back to get more help and you can see this answer as a right one if helpful to you.